# Show existence of ring homomorphism or prove that there is no such

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is it possible to find two rings with unity $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ (s. t. $\mathrm{char}\; R_{1}>0$ and $\mathrm{char}\;R_{2}=0$), such that there exists a non-trivial homomorphism $\varphi: R_{1}\rightarrow R_{2}$?

So I found out that if we prove existence of preimage of $1_{R_{2}}$ then we are done (I am not sure even here).

I feel like it is a trivial question, however this one stumped me, well, that happens... I don't need a solution but rather some small hint.

Answer (score 3):

Depends.

If a homomorphism is assumed to be unital (meaning $f(1)=1$), which is a typical assumption, then "no such homomorphism exists". Because $0=f(0)=f(n\cdot 1)=n\cdot f(1)=n\cdot 1\neq 0$, where $n=char R_1>0$.

But for nonunital ring homomorphisms the answer is "yes, there are such homomorphisms". Consider any ring $R_1$ and let $R_2=R_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. Then $char R_2=0$ and $f:R_1\to R_2$ given by $f(r)=(r,0)$ is a nontrivial, nonunital ring homomorphism regardless of $R_1$ (assuming $R_1$ nontrivial).